# searching more than one line at a time

Tags: perl

```
Users of SSS:  (Total of 1 license issued;  Total of 0 licenses in use)

Users of DesignWare-Regression:  (Total of 1 licenses issued;  Total of
0 licenses in use)

Users of FusionVantageLmcInterface:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;
Total of 0 licenses in use)

Users of LMCSwift_Net:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 0
licenses in use)

Users of SNPS-Assertions:  (Total of 4 licenses issued;  Total of 0
licenses in use)

Users of VCSAMSCompiler_Net:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 0
licenses in use)

Users of VCSAMSRuntime_Net:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 0
licenses in use)

Users of VCSPostProcDebugger_Net:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total
of 0 licenses in use)

Users of VCSTools_Net:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 0
licenses in use)

Users of VCSiCompiler_Net:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 0
licenses in use)

Users of VCSiRuntime_Net:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 2
licenses in use)

Users of VT_Assertions:  (Total of 4 licenses issued;  Total of 0
licenses in use)

Users of VT_AssertionsRuntime:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of
0 licenses in use)

Users of VT_Coverage:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 0 licenses in use)

Users of VT_CoverageRuntime:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 0
licenses in use)

Users of VT_CoverageURG:  (Total of 3 licenses issued;  Total of 0
licenses in use)

Users of VT_Testbench:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 0
licenses in use)

Users of VT_TestbenchRuntime:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of
2 licenses in use)


Users of VT_Visual:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 2 licenses in use)

Users of XVCSDebugger:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 0
licenses in use)

Users of vera_comp:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 0 licenses in use)

Users of vera_debug:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 0 licenses in use)

Users of vera_rtime:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 0 licenses in use)
```

i have a data like this.in this  i want product name, number of licenses issued,number of licenses used ..how can i get it...please help

This is what i have of now.

```
    if ($_=~ m/.*users\s+of\s+(.*)\:\s+(Total\s+of\s+(\d)\s+licenses.*\;\A*\s+total\s+of\A*\‌​s+(\d)\A*\s+licenses\s+.*)/gmi)

{print "$1,$2,$3}";
```

Comment: Iam a beginner.my professor gave me this ...please help me..

Comment: please spend sometime on the net and post what you come up with, then we can help.

Comment: i tried from moring...iam getting the users and other thing when they are in single line...but i cant get other ...

Comment: this is my code                                                                    if ($_=~ m/.*users\s+of\s+(.*)\:\s+\(Total\s+of\s+(\d)\s+licenses.*\;\A*\s+total\s+of\A*\s+(\d)\A*\s+licenses\s+.*\)/gmi){print "$1,$2,$3}";

Comment: It is better to edit the original question to add the code you have tried rather than showing it in a comment.

Comment: The new code does not show how you read the file. Code like `if(m/.../g){action}` is normally used in a loop. The `.*` before `users` in your regular expression is not needed; it might be replaced by a `^` for start of line.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this fits your need. You had over-looked certain aspects, i had fixed those.

```
$Data = join '',<DATA>;
while ( $Data =~
    m/\G\s*Users\s*of\s*(.+?)\s*:
         \s*\(Total\s*of\s*(\d+)\s*licenses\s*issued\s*\;
         \s*Total\s*of\s*(\d+)\s*licenses\s*in\s*use\s*\)\s*/gmix)
     {
         print "$1,$2,$3\n";
     }
__DATA__
Users of vera_rtime:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 0 licenses in use)

Users of DesignWare-Regression:  (Total of 1 licenses issued;  Total of
0 licenses in use)

Users of FusionVantageLmcInterface:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;
Total of 0 licenses in use)

Users of LMCSwift_Net:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 0
licenses in use)


Users of SNPS-Assertions:  (Total of 4 licenses issued;  Total of 0
licenses in use)

Users of VCSAMSCompiler_Net:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 0
licenses in use)

Users of VCSAMSRuntime_Net:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 0
licenses in use)

Users of VCSPostProcDebugger_Net:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total
of 0 licenses in use)

Users of VCSTools_Net:  (Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 0
licenses in use)
```